# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a react app but after installing it and trying to run it it gives me this error below

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at processModule (C:\Users\salde\Desktop\salvo-app\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:93:38)
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Users\salde\Desktop\salvo-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:5:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\salde\Desktop\salvo-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\salde\Desktop\salvo-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:781:30
    at MultiModule.build (C:\Users\salde\Desktop\salvo-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\MultiModule.js:39:10)
    at Compilation.buildModule (C:\Users\salde\Desktop\salvo-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
    at C:\Users\salde\Desktop\salvo-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1111:12
s\webpack\lib\util\Semaphore.js:29:4)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! salvo-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the salvo-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\salde\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-19T13_48_14_021Z-debug.log
```

I typed `npx create-react-app my-app`
then cd to my-app and then npm start

any Ideas what could have I done wrong?
thanks

Comment: I have same issue, installed fresh new react app with latest eslint

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some bugs with eslint-plugin-react or eslint itself. i'v tried to npm i --save-dev eslint@6.8.0 and thats fixed my problem